# No operation found on MBean

Tags: java, jmx

Basically I am following the standard basic JMX tutorial and registering a MXBean with two methods.

```
public interface QueueSamplerMXBean {
    public QueueSample getQueueSample();
    public void clearQueue();
}
```

However, when I try to query the registered MBean, it only returns the clearQueue. Here is my sample program:

```
MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();

// Construct the ObjectName for the QueueSampler MXBean we will register
ObjectName mxbeanName = new ObjectName("com.example:type=QueueSampler");

// Create the Queue Sampler MXBean
Queue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(10);
queue.add("Request-1");
queue.add("Request-2");
queue.add("Request-3");
QueueSampler mxbean = new QueueSampler(queue);

// Register the Queue Sampler MXBean
mbs.registerMBean(mxbean, mxbeanName);

MBeanInfo info = mbs.getMBeanInfo(mxbeanName);
for(MBeanOperationInfo op : info.getOperations()) {
    System.out.println("operation = " + op.getName());
}
```

I think this is the reason why I keeps getting "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException. ... No operation XXXXXX(method name invoked) found on MBean ..... I am getting this exception while trying to invoke the MXBean method through Jolokia agent (JSON to JMX bridge). I have no problem invoking methods with void return type.

Anyone have any clues why getOperations does NOT return me the method with an JavaBean object as a return type? This is so weird. I must be missing something really simple.

Thanks!

Comment: Basically it is the convention JMX applies. Any method that starts with **get** is treated as an attribute instead of operation even though the implementation class doesn't have such attribute. So when you try to call the method from something like Jolokia, you would need to use the **read** operation and pass in the "attribute" name instead, in my case it would be /read/..../QueueSample

Comment: thanks my friend!! :DDDD

Answer (score 1):

I bet you have an attribute `queueSample` on your MBean instead, as `getFoo` is usually turned in to a readable attribute `foo` , `setFoo` into a writable one and if you have getter and setter, the attribute is r/w.

Use a tool like `jconsole` to connect to the VM and inspect your MBean.

Answer (score 0):

The method should be:

public QueueSampleMBean getQueueSample();

And QueueSample should implement QueueSampleMBean (and only expose simple types).